# get day of week in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have an output string which will contain one of the weekdays (Monday, Tuesday, etc).

For example,

```
"Some tex may appear before week day, Monday, will only be one occurrence of the weekday"
```

How do I retrieve the weekday from the string?

I can use a chain of IF statements to see if the string contains the weekday, but wanted to know if there was a more concise way?

Comment: This is kind of vague, but it seems like Regex won't help you much. Maybe you want to use `String.Contains` over a list of acceptable Day formats?

Comment: Do you want to replace it with something, remove it from the string or just see if it exists in the string?

Comment: Some more examples of input strings would be helpful. We can't see a pattern from a single example.

Comment: You want a list of days contained in the string right?

Comment: In the example above I would like the string "Thursday".

Comment: Why not just have the person check off the days with a checkboxlist?

Comment: Here: `"some text here, Thursday maybe text here".Split()[3]`

Comment: I don't know but you could have an Enum representing the days of the week. 
Split your string try to parse to an enum field somehow and compare if it matches. 

I'm no guru on C# but it would be shocking if you can't do that.

Comment: @LewsTherin - There are such enums already in the BCL.

Comment: @Oded I would have made it an answer but I have no idea how to write the code. I'd rather leave it to the pros :D

Comment: Can `blah` be different in each case or must they always be the same?

Answer (score 3):

This will build a regex that will find a day of the week.

```
var pattern = string.Format("({0})", string.Join("|", Enum.GetValues(typeof (DayOfWeek)).OfType<DayOfWeek>()));

var match = Regex.Match("some text here, Thursday maybe text here", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Assert.AreEqual("Thursday", match.Value);
```

Comment: For bonus points, make it culture sensitive ;)

Comment: @Oded:  I am a culturally-insensitive clod.  ;-)  Though a cultural-sensitive solution would be much more correct than this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something that looks for the index of the day, and then pull it from there.  Something like:

```
int first = str.IndexOf("Thursday");
int last = str.LastIndexOf("Thursday");
string day = str.Substring(first, last);
```

Code may not be 100% right, but the something similar should work.  And if there's more than one day, you'll obviously have to do this for each day.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it exist in a string

```
string text = "some text here, Thursday maybe text here";

if (text.Contains("thursday")) // Make text to lower case before checking
{
    ...
}
```

To remove it

```
text = text.Replace("thursday", ""); // Regex would be better to make it case-insensitive
```

Do this for all the days of the week.

Comment: Austin Salonen's example is great, check it out instead!

Answer (score 0):

```
int intCounter = 0;
string strWeekName = "";
string strContent = "Some text wednesday";
strContent = strContent.ToUpper;
while (intCounter < 7) {
  if (strContent.Contains(DateAndTime.WeekdayName(intCounter).ToUpper())) {
      strWeekName = DateAndTime.WeekdayName(intCounter);
      break; 
  }
  intCounter++; 
}

MsgBox "Weekday " + strWeekName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the case is not considered & only one instance occurs :

```
string found = "";

string myString = "some text here, Thursday maybe text here";

foreach (string str in myString.Split())

    foreach (DayOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))

        if(day.ToString() == str) found = str;
```